# How does StreamWriter class actually work?

Tags: c#, file-io, filestream, streamreader, streamwriter

Considering a file named `!file io test.txt`, containing the following lines:

```
1|adrian|louis|50000
2|jeff|potato|200000
3|michael|de santa|980000
4|jemmy|mccormic|500400
5|jack|cohen|4300000
6|ethan|trump|1080000
```

and considering this code segment:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\McLovin\Desktop\!file io test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
char c = (char)sr.Read(); // line 4
sw.Write('~');
sw.Flush();
```

After line number 4, the file pointer should have read the first character and moved itself to the second one. This works as expected when I read the file, but when I write the file pointer, it always points to the end of the file and starts writing there. If I comment the line 4 out, the `StreamWriter` will work as it should (overwrite the file from the beginning).

This current code produces:

```
1|adrian|louis|50000
2|jeff|potato|200000
3|michael|de santa|980000
4|jemmy|mccormic|500400
5|jack|cohen|4300000
6|ethan|trump|108000
~
```

but I want it to produce this:

```
1~adrian|louis|50000
2|jeff|potato|200000
3|michael|de santa|980000
4|jemmy|mccormic|500400
5|jack|cohen|4300000
6|ethan|trump|1080000
```

Comment: Basically, I'd recommend avoiding using both `StreamWriter` and `StreamReader` wrapping the same `Stream`. It's almost certainly a matter of `StreamReader.Read` reading a whole buffer of data...

Comment: By the way, you can look at the `StreamWriter` internals here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs,9e38cb1c84769eba

Comment: Agree @JonSkeet. Reset the stream pos to 0, to start writing from BOF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it that way you'll need to reset the stream after the read.

```
numOfBytesRead = 1;
fs.Seek(numOfBytesRead, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

I suspect the issue is with the internal buffer of the **StreamReader**. You get a single byte output but internally the reader has read ahead a bit to fill the buffer and leaves the position of the stream wherever it has actually read to.

The constructor overload you use results in a buffer size of 1024 bytes. The contents of your file is well below that so the position of the stream is left at the end after your read call. If you increase the size of your file beyond that you will see the tilde won't be written at the end anymore.

*Interestingly enough it also looks like the buffer cannot be set below 128 bytes.*